# Determine total amount of matching combinations (1:1) in a maximum node graph

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science

Is there a "non-bruteforce" way to determine the total amount of matching combinations (1:1) between a set of nodes with corresponding edges?

Every node can only be connected to a single other node.

Say I have a dataset like this:

- Node 1

  - Edge to 2, 3 and 5
- Node 2

  - Edge to 1, and 3
- Node 3

  - Edge to 1 and 4
- Node 4

  - Edge to 3 and 5
- Node 5

  - Edge to 1 and 4

[image]

This particular set has a maximum of two matches for each combination, as every node can only be connected to one other node.

[image]

This particular dataset has a total of 6 maximum combinations in a maximum matching result (Where every node, that can be matched is matched)

Attempting to count larger datasets with more edges relating the nodes easily gets very difficult, which is why I'm wondering if there is a better way (other than bruteforcing) to calculate the total amount of combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Counting the number of matchings, or the number of maximum matchings, are both #P-complete ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#Counting_problems)).

#P-completeness is kind-of analogous to NP-completeness, but for counting problems.
That essentially means that, unfortunately, there is no better way than bruteforcing.

Comment: That's very unfortunate. Is there any other heuristic, that I can calculate that would give me an indication of how costly a set of nodes and edges would be to bruteforce? The reason I ask this, is because I am actually doing an optimized bruteforce on the dataset. I wish to know ahead of time if I should split the graph into smaller subsets, to  bruteforce them seperately. That's why I need to have some kind of idea, of how costly the bruteforce will become.

Comment: I think you could use $n!$ to get a rough idea on the number of cases to bruteforce.  At least this works for counting the number of perfect matchings: these relate to computing the permanent of a matrix (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent#Perfect_matchings), and computing the permanent requires evaluating $n!$ terms.  You could also check about approximating the permanent (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_the_permanent), but on that I'm certainly no expert.